# Using C++ implementation of OpenSSL to decrypt data

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

I am trying to decrypt AES-256-CBC encrypted data.

I can decrypt the entire file, but I get additional characters at the end. I also get an error from the OpenSSL libraries that says this...

`EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:532`

Here is my decryption function which is right out of the wiki:

```
int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    int plaintext_len = 0;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len = 0;
    plaintext_len = 0;
    int error = 0;
    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

    if(ctx == NULL)
    {
        handleErrors(0,1);
    }

    error = EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
    handleErrors(error,2);

    error = EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx,plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len);
    handleErrors(error, 3);

    plaintext_len = len;

    error = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx,plaintext + len, &len);
    handleErrors(error, 4);

    plaintext_len += len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}
```

Note that I am passing in raw bytes using the `uint8_t` type, but converted it for this function. The plain text that is working contains the file, plus some additional characters at the end.

Here is the encrypted data in hex:

```
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
```

Here is the AES encryption key in hex

```
174126874a7c7f9a44da4f559cfd628586894e86f7e2eb0561a0809b7a294fd4
```

Here is the IV

```
603da7b9f9c365219a8121e528e7dddc
```

The result is

```
echo Y | format H: /q /x /fs:NTFS

@echo off

echo.
echo.Stopping the Backup Exec services...
echo.

net stop "BackupExecAgentBrowser"
net stop "BackupExecJobEngine" 
net stop "BackupExecManagementService"
net stop "BackupExecRPCService"
net stop "BackupExecDeviceMediaService"
net stop "BackupExecAgentAccelerator"
net stop "bedbg"

echo.
echo.Starting the Backup Exec services...
echo.

net start "bedbg"
net start "BackupExecAgentAccelerator"
net start "BackupExecDeviceMediaService"
net start "BackupExecRPCService"
net start "BackupExecManagementService"
net start "BackupExecJobEngine"
net start "BackupExecAgentBrowser"
pause
exitC��Q�H
```

Notice the odd few characters at the end.

Also note, I've tried the same thing in Python and am getting the same results. I believe it has to do with the padding. But I don't know if I am supposed to pad the encrypted data, and if so, with what data, or what...

Comment: Where does the encrypted data come from? It looks like who or whatever encrypted it didn’t properly pad the plaintext beforehand. (Also you missed of the IV for people to reproduce–for anyone else who wants it it’s `603da7b9f9c365219a8121e528e7dddc`).

Comment: Thanks, I added the IV to the post. The source of this is from ransom ware. I don't exactly know how they encrypted it.

Comment: CBC mode provides confidentiality only, and you usually must add a MAC to use CBC mode safely. You should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.